# Water rising and descending

Tags: game-development, roblox

im in a process of making a roblox game. I want to make the water rise and descend again down. I think i did something wrong with coding,(its my second day of coding and i cant find any video on it) im not sure what. So everytime i run roblox after 1st descending and starting of 2nd game, it freezes,water dissapears and it throws a error: Script timeout: exhausted allowed execution time. Here is my code:

```html
wait(21)
t = 17
repeat
    t = t-1
    script.Parent.Position = script.Parent.Position + Vector3.new(0, 1, 0)
    wait(2)
until
    t == 0
wait(1)
t = 17
repeat
    t = t-1
    script.Parent.Position = script.Parent.Position + Vector3.new(0, -1, 0)
    wait(0.5)
until
t == 0
wait(9)
t = 17

while true do
    t = t-1
    script.Parent.Position = script.Parent.Position + Vector3.new(0, 1, 0)
end
wait(2)
while false do
    t = t-1
    script.Parent.Position = script.Parent.Position + Vector3.new(0, -1, 0)
end
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript` (no JS in the code), `scripting` which already mentions in the description that it is way too unspecific (_"This tag is non-specific. Use a specific script tag instead."_), and `game-development`?

Answer (score 1):

> Script timeout: exhausted allowed execution time.

Because the code never stops looping here:

```
while true do
  //...
end
```

This will continue to loop forever.  (Well, for as long as `true` is `true`.  And I can't think of a condition in which it wouldn't be.)

Contrast that with your loops above:

```
t = 17
repeat
  t = t-1
  //...
until
  t == 0
```

In this case the loop explicitly repeats "until `t` equals `0`", and each iteration of the loop brings `t` one step closer to `0`.

Modify your later loops to have similar structures and conditions.  For example:

```
t = 17
while t > 0 do
  t = t-1
  //...
end
```

Note also that this loop will *never* execute:

```
while false do
  //...
end
```

Because `false` is never `true`.  Now is a good time to take a step back and consider the logic of what you want these loops to do.  Just like with your first two loops, modify your second two loops to indicate how many times they should repeat.

Comment: Wait, so what do i have to do to make it work? its my first time coding a game, btw thx for help but how do i modify it?

Comment: @Rec: Exactly as the answer describes, you have to have a logical condition to *end the loop*.  It can't just repeat infinitely or you'll get the exact error you're getting.  For your third and fourth loops, how many times do you want them to repeat?  Make them repeat that many times, instead of *infinitely* and *never* like they currently do.

Comment: But wait, i want them to repeat like idk 100 times or something. Where do i put 100

Comment: @Rec: You'll have to look up the specifics for the language you're using (does Roblox use something called Lua maybe?), but semantically what you're describing for a *while loop* would be stated like: "while t is less than 100"  So in most languages that might look like: `while t < 100`  So before the loop body you would initialize `t` (or any variable you like, I'm just using `t` because your code does) to some value (like `0`) and within the loop body you would modify `t` (like by adding `1` to it).  Well-written code very closely matches its semantic description.  You are encouraged to try.